# Application restarting after SQLite Database updates

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, tauri

i am learning Tauri and want to use a SQLite Database with the diesel ORM.

## Problem

The App ist always restarting after a change in the Databasefile.

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.56s
        Info File src-tauri/DB.db changed. Rebuilding application...
warning: #[table_name] attribute form is deprecated
  = help: use `#[diesel(table_name = categories)]` instead
```

i got the example from here:
https://morioh.com/p/ea3442d4bb16

I already found out, that you need to add the

```
TAURI_DEV_WATCHER_IGNORE_FILE=.taurignore
```

variable in the .env file and wrtie: **store.sqlite** but it seems like its not working.

## Information

### Versions

```
diesel = {version="2.0.3", features=["sqlite"]}
```

### Basic Folderstructure

```bash
projectname/
    ├── .env
    ├── .taurignore
    └── src-tauri/
        ├── main.rs
        └── dbfile.db
```

### taurigrnore file

```
dbfile.db
```

How can i implement this properly or is there any Documentation about the .taurignore file?

## Solution

Ok i found the Solution the Path in the .taurignore file has to be the relative Path from the root folder:
src-tauri/Db.db

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow your question as it misses some important information (like which tauri/diesel/… versions you are using). Based on the included message I would guess that you somehow need to exclude `src-tauri/DB.db` from the list of monitored files of your watch tool. As information about that tool are missing as well from your question it's not possible to say how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the Response.
I inserted more Information to the Question. 
I hope this helps.